# pouchdb-find + $in : no matching index found

Tags: nosql, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a secondary non-unique key named 'tileId' which I would like to use for searching. Therefore, I have created the following index:

```
this.pouchDB.createIndex({
  index: {
          fields: ['tileId']
         }
  });
```

Then it works fine when I'm using the following selector:

```
selector: {tileId: 1234567}
```

But when I try to search for a list of values with the following selector, it works but gives a warning about no matching index found:

```
selector: {tileId: {$in, [1234567, 2345678]}}
```

1. What am I doing wrong and what should I change to query for documents, where (tileId === 1234567) OR (tileId === 2345678) OR (tileId === ... any other value from the array)?
2. Finally, I want to add several more similar fields to this query to get something like this:

   ```
   selector: {tileId: {$in, [1234567, 2345678]},
              category: {$in, [list of categories]},
              subcategory: {$in, [list of subcategories]}
             }
   ```

   Is it doable, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the current implementation of PouchDB Find only utilizes an index for contiguous keys (`tileId` values in this case). If you specify a query which interrogates a disparate set of records by `tileId` e.g. using an `$or` or `$in` clause, the (very basic) query planner elects not to use `tileId` as the basis for an index scan at all.

I think you'd be better off issuing multiple queries rather than using `$in` for the `tileId`. The additional filters maybe relatively cheap if the number of documents with the specified `tileId` is modest.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Though, I was expecting that since they have this '$in' qualifier, there should be a way to use it gracefully. How do think, Is there a way to get it working via map/reduce API?